# AWS trigger to Lambda ALIAS from S3 upload timing out

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have the following need: I want an S3 file upload to trigger a *specific alias* of a Lambda function.

Everything works fine when the trigger points to the Lambda *without* any alias but as soon as I add the alias to the ARN, the lambda seems triggered but times out after 3 seconds (despite the fact that the main lambda timeout is set to 60 seconds and works just fine).

Shown below: the S3 trigger to the alias
[image]

Shown below: the trigger being successfully defined at the Lambda *alias* level
[image]

Shown below: the logs with the timeout
[image]

Additional notes:

- I have added the InvokeFunction permissions to S3 bucket both at the main Lambda and at the alias level. And I believe the aliases inherit the main lambda resource access (that's what the console shows).
- For the moment, there is only one version of the Lambda and all aliases point to it (version "1", as shown in the logs) .
- If I trigger the Lambda alias from the console, it also times out. And it doesn't show any of the (many) custom application logs that the main Lambda shows.

What am I missing? Could it be that the alias has a dedicated timeout configuration?

Comment: You need to publish your lambda code (with logging) and config (with timeout) as a new version and then point the alias to that version.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [@luk2302](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2442804/luk2302), it appears that re-deploying the same Lambda will *not* update the alias, that will somehow keep a reference to previous deployment(s).

Below is the warning message from the AWS Console when you delete an alias.

[image]

I have updated the CDK code to generate a new version and updated the alias accordingly and it looks like things are working properly now. Thank you!